# Unexpected value for default_scope

Tags: gcloud

I have set up an entire environment using gcloud compute (with great success) and am now trying to script the updating of an image in an instance template.  First step is to switch off auto delete on the the instance I wish to use as the base.  I cannot get it to work without the following error:

```
$ gcloud compute --project testing-141313 instances set-disk-auto-delete mantle-test-robot-dtrc --zone europe-west1-b --device-name /dev/sda --no-auto-delete
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.set-disk-auto-delete) Unexpected
>   value for default_scope ScopeEnum.GLOBAL, expected None or ZONE

Comment: This appears to be a bug. Can you file it here: https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list.

Comment: I have filed a bug as requested, thanks.